# Обновление методов и API в telegram-клиенте на Android

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram

Всем привет. В декабре 2021 года телеграм отключил свои старые клиенты, теперь авторизироваться в них невозможно. У меня есть исходный код старой версии телеграм (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/f338a88eb4c48348378fb9575fa6b63ff80bbec3). Подскажите пожалуйста, как оживить данную версию. Будет ли эта версия работать если я внесу в неё свои app_hash/app_id и скомпилирую в Android Studio или нужно редактировать, обновлять какие-то методы? Если да, то как привести приложение в чувство?